# How to forward conversation from formflow to QnaDialog

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, formflow

Hi Guys im new to bot development, and im trying to figure out how can i forward the conversation to a QnaDialog after formflow. My formflow simply asks the user his/her name after he/she was identified, it would simply say hi (username) afterwards what I want is that any message afterwards would be forwarded to a QnaDialog already since the user was already identified. I tried adding a checker once to flag that a greeting was done already, however since you are only allowed one Conversation.SendAsync I am now lost for ideas on how to correct this properly.

**FORMFLOW**

```
  public class ProfileForm
{
    // these are the fields that will hold the data
    // we will gather with the form
    [Prompt("What is your name? {||}")]
    public string Name;

    // This method 'builds' the form 
    // This method will be called by code we will place
    // in the MakeRootDialog method of the MessagesControlller.cs file
    public static IForm<ProfileForm> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<ProfileForm>()
                .Message("Welcome to the profile bot!")
                .OnCompletion(async (context, profileForm) =>
                {
                    // Set BotUserData
                    context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<bool>("ProfileComplete", true);
                    context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>("Name", profileForm.Name);
                    // Tell the user that the form is complete
                    await context.PostAsync("Your profile is complete.");
                })
                .Build();
    }


}
```

**MessageController**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            //ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
            //await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new QnADialog());

            #region Formflow

            // Get any saved values
            StateClient sc = activity.GetStateClient();
            BotData userData = sc.BotState.GetPrivateConversationData(
                activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id, activity.From.Id);
            var boolProfileComplete = userData.GetProperty<bool>("ProfileComplete");
            if (!boolProfileComplete)
            {
                // Call our FormFlow by calling MakeRootDialog
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRootDialog);
            }
            else
            {
                //Check if Personalized Greeting is done
                if (userData.GetProperty<bool>("Greet"))
                {
                    //this doesnt work since their should be only one Conversation.SendAsync.

                    //ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                    //await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new QnADialog());
                }
                else
                {
                    // Get the saved profile values
                    var Name = userData.GetProperty<string>("Name");
                    userData.SetProperty<bool>("Greet", true);
                    sc.BotState.SetPrivateConversationData(activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id,activity.From.Id, userData);
                    ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                    Activity replyMessage = activity.CreateReply(string.Format("Hi {0}!", Name));
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(replyMessage);
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using your example. I made a few small changes but nothing you wouldn't be able to spot. A bit of explanation:

**Controller**: I cleaned it up. It should really only be calling the root dialog. This is much cleaner.

**RootDialog**: Will first call the form. If the form was successful it will continue to the QnA dialog.

**ProfileForm**: only deleted the FormCompleted boolean. Was not necessary.

**QnADialog**: Will start the dialog and ask a question, using the name filled in. I kept the default code to get some feedback.

Hope this helps

### Controller

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

### RootDialog

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task ResumeAfterForm(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<ProfileForm> result)
    {
        if (context.PrivateConversationData.TryGetValue("Name", out string name))
        {
            context.Call(new QnADialog(), MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Something went wrong.");
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var form = new FormDialog<ProfileForm>(new ProfileForm(), ProfileForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
        context.Call(form, ResumeAfterForm);
    }
}
```

### ProfileForm

```
[Serializable]
public class ProfileForm
{
    // these are the fields that will hold the data
    // we will gather with the form
    [Prompt("What is your name? {||}")]
    public string Name;

    // This method 'builds' the form 
    // This method will be called by code we will place
    // in the MakeRootDialog method of the MessagesControlller.cs file
    public static IForm<ProfileForm> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<ProfileForm>()
                .Message("Welcome to the profile bot!")
                .OnCompletion(async (context, profileForm) =>
                {
                    // Set BotUserData
                    //context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<bool>("ProfileComplete", true);
                    context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>("Name", profileForm.Name);
                    // Tell the user that the form is complete
                    await context.PostAsync("Your profile is complete.");
                })
                .Build();
    }
}
```

### QnADialog

```
[Serializable]
public class QnADialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.PrivateConversationData.TryGetValue("Name", out string name);
        await context.PostAsync($"Hello {name}. The QnA Dialog was started. Ask a question.");
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        // calculate something for us to return
        int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

        // return our reply to the user
        await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this man! I was able to make this work! Is there a way where in i can temporary save a user and bot conversation which later I can use if the user opt to send it via email?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43602478/storing-conversation-of-a-specific-user-temporarily

Comment: That is possible. Take a look at the [data stores](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/stateapi.html).
You can either get a state client from your activity by using `StateClient stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();` and accessing one of the 3 data stores. You can also access the stores directly through the dialog context `context.UserData`.

Please note that you can only store object smaller then 32kb. Although this is still pretty large, it's good to know you shouldn't make your object too large.

Comment: hey man i found a bug, when i try to enter " the form dialog will start all over again. where can i catch it?

Comment: hey man how come everytime i attempt to add any attachment, my formbuilder restarts?

Comment: Exception: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
[File of type 'text/plain']

Comment: Adding an attachment won't simply work with this solution. handling attachments requires a different approach because of the way they are handled in the framework. I would suggest starting a different question if you are experiencing problems and presenting your code so we can have a look.